# Shopp Database Upgrade Required loop

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, shopp

After updating the Shopp plugin to version 1.3.3 in wordpress version 3.9.1, I activated the plugin, and when trying to access the plugins admin page, I get a page that saying:

> Shopp has been updated!
>
> Before you can use the new version of Shopp, your database needs to be upgraded.
>
> Your storefront has been switched to maintenance mode until the database upgrade is completed.
>
> IMPORTANT: Be sure to backup your database to prevent a loss of data! How do I backup?
>   To upgrade, you simply need to reactivate Shopp:
>
> Click the Continue… button below to deactivate Shopp
>
> In the WordPress Plugins manager, click the Activate link for Shopp to reactivate and upgrade the Shopp database

I am running on Mamp 3.0

I follow the instructions, deactivate and activate the plugin, and I still recieve the same update required page.

I have verified that the **db_version** in my **options** database table matches the **$wp_db_version** in **wp-includes/version.php**.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem where WP would use mysqli automatically when available.
Adding this command to wp-config.php made it work again.

```
define('WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

RST is almost correct.

He said WP-config.sys but you really want to add it to wp-config.php

Add `define('WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL',true);` to your wp-config.php file in the root of you WordPress install.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the typo, I have adjusted the text of my answer. You didn't have to post a new answer, a comment to my answer would have been sufficient too.